# Подскажите какое свойство дописать чтобы div при на видении мыши появлялся блок и закрывал рядом с ним другой блок

Tags: css

Подскажите какое свойство дописать чтобы div при на видении мыши появлялся блок и закрывал рядом с ним другой блок, проще говоря я хочу расширить первый блок при навидении[image: введите сюда описание изображения] На картинке пометил, нужно чтобы желтый фон был полностью в красной рамке, у меня не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Код ваших попыток хорошо бы добавить в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Если кратко ответ такой: `div:hover {}` Свойства будут добавлены к блоку когда мышь находится над блоком. И убраны, когда мышь вне блока.

Чтобы реализовать то, что вы хотите, нужно чтобы каждый блок серого цвета находился на фиксированной позиции (`position: absolute`), иначе не будет работать свойство `z-index`, которое требуется чтобы желтый блок был поверх серых, а так же увеличившиеся размеры желтого блока сдвинут со своих мест серые блок. Думаю вы не такого эффекта хотите.

Answer (score 0):

я не знаю как та порнуха в реальном проекте будет выглядеть но вот так вроде:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.clear,
.clear:after,
.clear:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.block {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
}
.block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.block:first-child {
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
.block:first-child:hover {
  width: 600px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.block:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 33.5%;
}
.block:nth-child(2):hover {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
}
.block:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 67%;
}
.block:nth-child(3):hover {
  width: 600px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper clear">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Пример в розовом окне на codepen:наведи

> http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/rLPakY?editors=110